# How would I access the data member of a struct within a class?

Tags: c++

I've wrote this class, and the member function, and have created the object in the main function. It calls the show function just fine, but the show function itself says that it cannot access root because it is not declared in scope. I set the data members as public, and I didn't think I would need a getter/setter for this. What's the best way to allow show() access to root?

```
class bst
{
            public:
            struct Node
            {
                public:
                int data;
                struct Node *left;
                struct Node *right;
                Node* root = NULL;
            };

            void show();

};

void bst::show()
{
    if(root == NULL) return;

    show(root->left);       //Visit left subtree
    printf("%d ",root->data);  //Print data
    show(root->right);      // Visit right subtree
}
```

Comment: using `this->root`? Could you share your complete code?

Comment: `root` should be member of `bst`, not `bst::Node`. And I think `bst::show()` should take `Node *` as its parameter.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Good point on `root` likely being in the wrong place. That said, `show` is a member function, so if `root` is a member of `bst`, `bst::show` shouldn't need to take it as a parameter.

Comment: @ShadowRanger But OP's doing sth like `show(root->left);`.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Ah, true. There are some design problems that need to be worked out here. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger This code was originally not a class, so I'm trying to make it into one.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you actually defined an instance of `struct Node` as a member of your `bst` class. You defined the nested class, but declared no instances of it. Declare one, and you can use the name it's declared under to make this work, e.g.:

```
class bst
{
            public:
            struct Node
            {
                public:
                int data;
                struct Node *left;
                struct Node *right;
                Node* root = NULL;
            };
            Node node;

            void show();
};


void bst::show()
{
    if(node.root == NULL) return;

    show(node.root->left);       //Visit left subtree
    printf("%d ",node.root->data);  //Print data
    show(node.root->right);      // Visit right subtree
}
```

It's possible you meant for `root` to be a member of `bst`, in which case you'd rearrange things to put it in `bst`, not the declaration of the `Node` class:

```
class bst
{
            public:
            struct Node
            {
                public:
                int data;
                struct Node *left;
                struct Node *right;
            };
            Node* root = NULL;

            void show();
};
```

in which case you wouldn't need to qualify the references with `node.` as shown in the first example.

Comment: This resolves the compile issue for one line of the code, but how would I go about doing the recursive call with this?

show(root->left);

Comment: @Raznarok: Seems like `show` should really be a method of the `Node`s themselves, where they know how to display themselves and their children recursively (the recursive calls would be `left->show()` and `right->show()` in this design). `bst`s `show` would be a trivial wrapper that does nothing but call `root->show()`. The alternative (that keeps the logic in `bst`) would be to have a `show` that takes a `Node*` argument, `show(Node *node)`, where again, `show()` with no arguments is a wrapper than invokes `show(root)`, and the one-arg `show` would recurse with `show(node->left)`, etc.